# Get specific data from json result by using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to get some json result by using curl. But I don't want to get all of the results. I just want to get a specific parameter from it. So what should I do?

**This is my method:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sample.jsp?id=123456");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$parts = parse_str($output);
$memberid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query['memberid ']);
```

**I get this result:**

```
{"memberid ":"000000000","cardNumber":"111111111","result":"OK"}
```

**But actually I just want**

```
000000000
```

Please help.

Comment: do `json_decode('string',true)` and then use array index to read it.

Comment: here is the link to `json_decode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Are you really asking how to decode JSON? Or it's actually a complex question about making the server send only partial data?

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = json_decode("{"memberid ":"000000000","cardNumber":"111111111","result":"OK"}", true);
echo $json["memberid"];
```

Comment: can I use $json = json_decode($output, true);
echo $json["memberid"];

Answer (score -1):

Two options: either change the server so it sends only what you need, or parse the response and extract the data.